# Creating filters dynamically with ng-click and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Right now, I have a bunch of filters that use ng-click to filter some JSON data pulled in from a factory:

```
<ul class="brands">
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="brandFilter = null">All</li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="brandFilter = { 'manufacturer' : 'Apple' }">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="brandFilter = { 'manufacturer' : 'Samsung' }">Samsung</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="brandFilter = { 'manufacturer' : 'HTC' }">HTC</a></li>
</ul>
<div ng-controller="phonesController">
    <div class="phonesContent">
        <article ng-repeat="phones in phoneData | filter:brandFilter" class="phone-article">
            <img src="{{ phones.image }}" alt="{{ phones.name }}" class="phone-img">
            <p>{{ phones.name }}</p>
            <p>Price: ${{ phones.price }}</p>
            <p>No term: ${{ phones.no-term }}</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works well, but I'm wondering how I can programmatically generate the links and use ng-click to filter. My best attempt so far:

```
<div ng-controller="phonesController">
    <ul class="brands">
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="brandFilter = null">All</li>
        <li ng-repeat="phones in phoneData | unique: 'manufacturer'"><a href="#" ng-click="brandFilter = { 'manufacturer' = phones.manufacturer }">{{ phones.manufacturer }}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="phonesContent">
        <article ng-repeat="phones in phoneData | filter:brandFilter" class="phone-article">
            <img src="{{ phones.image }}" alt="{{ phones.name }}" class="phone-img">
            <p>{{ phones.name }}</p>
            <p>Price: ${{ phones.price }}</p>
            <p>No term: ${{ phones.no-term }}</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

The links are generating properly and the data is showing up in the phonesContent div, but the filtering is not working. I keep getting a $parse:syntax error so something is wrong with my expression where `brandFilter = { 'manufacturer' = phones.manufacturer }` (I think).

Comment: Shouldn't it be { 'manufacturer' : phones.manufacturer } instead of { 'manufacturer' = phones.manufacturer }?

Comment: @Rob is correct, Angular expressions are evaluated as JavaScript and must have correct syntax.

Comment: Ahh good catch - I totally missed that. That resolved the syntax error, but it's still not filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Rob has pointed out why your code is not working, but I would say it's best to avoid having assignment statements in your directives. That way the interface to your controler is clearly defined.

I'd suggest adding a scope function `setFilter()` to your controller that sets the filter value:

```
$scope.setFilter = function (value) {
    $scope.brandFilter = value ? { manufacturer: value } : null;
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
<li><a href="#" ng-click="setFilter(null)">All</li>
<li ng-repeat="phones in phoneData | unique: 'manufacturer'">
<a href="#" ng-click="setFilter(phones.manufacturer)">{{ phones.manufacturer }}</a>
</li>
```